# Google maps signed-in hybrid app stuck

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, css, google-maps

I'm making a hybrid app for school.
I got the map working however i wanted my users to be able to save their locations on the app. After signing in on mobile i seem to be stuck on a white screen (ios)

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true">
</script>
```

can i somehow restart the app or reload the app after signing in? I haven't found a way use a function after signing in.

bonus question: is there a way get live data when using the app? like what call it makes?

Comment: You can try google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); to "reload" the map

Comment: It didn't work. i still haven't found the event that triggers when somebody signs in on google maps

Answer (score 0):

You could use the asynchronous loading of the Gmaps API:
(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async). It provides us with a callback function, which is called once the scripts finish loading and might help you develop a refresh mechanism to resolve the problem.